# Лоадер css - в виде вращения смайла

Tags: css, css3, svg, анимация

Я хочу воспроизвести анимацию `gif`  с помощью чистого `CSS` или `SVG`, возможно ли это сделать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Меня также устроят  другие подходящие решения.

Ниже приведен фрагмент, который  воспроизводит только статический смайлик.

```css
body {
  background: #fff;
  margin: 50px;
}

.loader {
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fff 50%, #51cf66 50%);
}

.loader:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #fff;
}

.dot {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #51cf66;
}

.dot:first-child {
  left: 10px;
  top: 10px;
}

.dot:last-child {
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="loader">
  <div class="dot"></div>
  <div class="dot"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/48232891/7394871

Answer (score 8):

Хотя эта анимация для смайликов может быть достигнута с использованием  `CSS`, но `SVG`, безусловно, является лучшим вариантом, главным образом, по следующим причинам:

- анимационные градиенты - не обеспечивают лучшую производительность
- сделать круг по каждой стороне смайла будет очень трудно,  без
  добавления семантической разметки
- SVG - это инструмент, созданный для того, чтобы было просто рисовать
  такие формы и оживлять их. Это упрощает их обслуживание, а код легче
  читать и понимать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И вот код (упрощенный из  [codepen](https://codepen.io/web-tiki/pen/zpmeKy)):

```css
svg {
  width:100px;
  height:auto;
  display:block;
  transform:rotateZ(0deg);
  margin:0 auto;
}
.smile, .eyes {
  stroke:teal;
  stroke-width:1.3;
  stroke-linecap:round;
  fill:transparent;
}
svg:hover {animation:rotate 1.2s cubic-bezier(0.65, 0.000, 0.75, 1.000);}
svg:hover .smile{animation: smile 1s cubic-bezier(0.2, 0.000, 0.8, 1.000);}
svg:hover .eyes{animation: eyes 1s cubic-bezier(.7, 0.000, 0.4, 1.000);}

@keyframes rotate { to { transform:rotateZ(720deg); } }
@keyframes smile { 50% { stroke-dasharray:20,5.1327;} }
@keyframes eyes  { 70% { stroke-dasharray:1,0,.5,23.6327;} }
 
 h1 {text-align:center;color:teal;}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 10 10">
  <circle class="smile" cx="5" cy="5" r="4" stroke-dashoffset="-.5" stroke-dasharray="11.5,13.6327" />
  <circle class="eyes" cx="5" cy="5" r="4" stroke-dashoffset="-15.5" stroke-dasharray="0,6.6327,0,17.5" />
</svg>
<h1>Hover me !</h1>
```

### Как создаются смайлик и анимация?

Этот смайлик выполнен с двумя элементами окружности SVG (один для глаз и один для улыбки) и атрибутом `stroke-dasharray`, чтобы сделать глаза и улыбку.

**Анимация:**

`Svg` вращается при наведении с использованием анимации `CSS`, а атрибут `stroke-dasharray` анимируется, чтобы глаза «исчезали» в улыбке.

Длина улыбки также изменяется примерно на 3/4 длины окружности.

**Easing function :**

Гладкий эффект достигается с помощью функций `easing` кривой Безье. Время анимации также изменено, чтобы приблизиться к желаемой анимации смайликов.

[Источник:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48305879/7394871) CSS rotating smiling face loader] @web-tiki